# Getting Error:Unexpected character '�' (1:2) while working Fabric.js in next js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, fabricjs

I'm trying to integrate Fabric Canvas in nextjs using *npm install fabric*. But getting Unexpected errors. I have tried to configure next.config.js, but the same error

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';
const designspace = () => {
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    setCanvas(initCanvas());
  }, []);
  const initCanvas = () => (
    new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
      height: 800,
      width: 800,
      backgroundColor: 'pink'
    })
  )


  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Fabric.js on React - fabric.Canvas('...')</h1>
      <canvas id="canvas" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default designspace;
```

next.config.js

```
 /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              esModule: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Error Message:./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

Comment: I don't have a copy of your files (nor that `canvas.node` file), but the type of error you're describing would make me wary of some non-ascii character existing at the start of a file. Try reading the bytes of the files (use HxD or some editor), and comparing with the bytes-value of that unknown character (convert the error string to bytes to see it). The most evil one would be a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), which you won't see when rendered (ref: `U+00A0`, alt code: `0160`, bytes: `0xC2A0`)

Comment: Thanks, Rouge, it s complicated to understand. But I found the solution. In the next js configuration you need to add ` webpack: (config) => {
    config.externals.push({
      sharp: 'commonjs sharp',
      canvas: 'commonjs canvas'
    })
    return config
  } `