# React file viewer Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use [react-doc-viewer](https://github.com/cyntler/react-doc-viewer/tree/main/src) to preview various files but I can't even run it for a single file. I'm trying like this:

```
'use client';

import DocViewer, { DocViewerRenderers } from '@cyntler/react-doc-viewer';


const file5 =
  'https://img.meta.com.vn/Data/image/2022/01/13/anh-dep-thien-nhien-3.jpg';

const docs = [
  {
    uri: file5,
  },
];

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <DocViewer pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers} documents={docs} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Unfortunately I've got [image]

On [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/epic-elbakyan-zlhkj6?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A18%2C15) it works fine. I'm usng NextJS

Comment: Does the second comment in the following post help?  Seems to be something to do with the way that the code gets packed during the build process:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/75986060/229326